# How to find jquery versin in richfaces

Tags: jquery, richfaces

What version of jquery that richfaces(3.3.3.CR1) supports. How to find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Richfaces uses the $ variable for something else, so you can't use it for jQuery. Instead you have to use the `jQuery` keyword. Therefore to find the version, use:

`jQuery.fn.jquery`

Answer (score 1):

When viewing any webpage that has jQuery you can enter the following into your Firebug/Web Inspector console to be told the version:

```
$.fn.jquery
```

For example, Stack Overflow is using 1.3.2

Comment: Iam getting this error for this query $.fn.jquery
TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined
What does it mean?

Comment: That means jQuery has not been defined and therefore is not being used on the site you are testing on.

Comment: @Kalpana try as "jQuery.fn.jquery" on firebug console. $.fn.jquery does not work on some pages.